# How to mock function for call multiple time

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I want to mock functions to using in unit test.

for example:

```
def b():
    return False


def a():
    b1 = b()
    b2 = b()
    .....
```

I want to see at first b() calling see "False" and at the second b() calling see "True"
or in other examples call "find_one" function twice

```
def check_item(user_id:str,item_id):
    # at first check user exist or not
    user=db.find_one('user',user_id)
    if not user:
        return False
    item=db.find_one('item',item_id)
    if not item:
        return False
    return True
```

(I know it's not a good way to handle checking items and should create a separate function and add own  logic to them :D )

For Mocking the "find_one" function we consider want at the first call isn't none and at the second call should see none.

Answer (score 1):

For handel this problem I use "patch" function from "unittest.mock" package and use Mock.side_effect.
when we use side_effect can define at first calling of some function return this mock data and at second function call return something else.
for see more about side_effect can see this  [url](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

```
from unittest.mock import patch

mock_user_data={'name':'John',....}
mock_item_data={'item_name':'Pen',...}
m = Mock()
m.side_effect = iter([mock_user_data,None ])

@patch('db.findone',m)
def test_check_item_function_with_nothnig_found_item():
    result = check_item(user_id='sdsas-sdsas-fdf52',item_id=2)
    assert result is False
```

now with mocking one function and call multiple time can mock return data based on need

---

---